# Pass value/text from table td to a modal?

Tags: angular

Hi good people from internet!
I can't pass a value/text from a table td to a modal variable.

I tried with innerHTML and innerText, which were the only solutions i 
found, but i get "[object HTMLTableCellElement]" instead of the actual 
value in the table td.

```
 HTML

 Table

  <table class="table table-striped table-light">
        <tr>
          <td #dado>Adress</td>
          <td>Rua Francisco Duarte Pedroso, 2B, 2º Esq</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-primary 
      btn-just-icon btn-sm" data-original-title="" title="" 
      (click)="openWindowCustomClass(content)">
              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td #dado>Postal Code</td>
          <td>1795-062, Algés</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-primary 
        btn-just-icon btn-sm" data-original-title="" title="" 
        (click)="openWindowCustomClass(content)">
              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Modal

   <ng-template #content let-modal>
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Alterar {{ dado }}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
        (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="editing">Nova {{ data }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduza a 
        nova {{ data }}" (input)="updateData($event)">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
        (click)="modal.save('saveClick')">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
        (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
     </div>
     </ng-template>

    --------------------------------------------------------------------

    Typescript

  openWindowCustomClass(content) {
     this.modalService.open(content, { windowClass: 'dark-modal' });
     this.dado = document.getElementById(this.dado).innerHTML;     
  }
```

Comment: To give you an answer, we need to know what this.modalService is. Is it an instance of Angular material modalService or you have written your own which shows the provided content in a modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular or angularjs, you should use its features for the click event and etc.
Assuming this, You should handle these by functions or methods in your component or controller to provide a model object for modal and binding it's properties to your modal view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state container/state management library like [ngxs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/) to share data through all your application and not only your page and modal. It cleaner and makes your information reusable through the whole app and for sure solves your actual problem